# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds LifecycleRegistry.popParentState

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I came across an exception on which I do not have a clue on how to fix it. Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:480)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.popParentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:194)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:293)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:332)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:137)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:123)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.dispatch(ReportFragment.java:121)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ReportFragment.onStart(ReportFragment.java:81)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2378)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1027)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1153)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2048)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:188)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6978)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I'm using `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1`.

---

### UPDATE

I got more informations. 
This is happening when I start an activity for result from within a `Fragment` by calling `Fragment.startActivityForResult()`. This `Fragment` is in "strange" place. Here it is the structure of its holding `Activity`

```
- HoldingActivity
-- HoldingFragment
--- FragmentPagerAdapter
---- MyFragment // This is where I call the startActivityForResult
```

Another point that might help is that every level of the `HoldingActivity` is using `ViewDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` and they all have a `ViewModel` attached to it.

The started `Avtivity` is hosting a `Fragment` and they also both use `ViewDataBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this)` and have a `ViewModel`.

Let me know if anything else could help resolve this issue, thanks.

Comment: it seems that you are trying to access an empty array..

Comment: But it's not something I try to do by myself. It's inside the Android API. It happened once when I tried to start an activity but I don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: it s hard to say somethng if u don't share your code

Comment: Well it's hard to share something because the stacktrace doesn't show me where, on my code, the error begins. It seems to happen just after a `startActivityForResult` but as I said I'm not able to reproduce it and the error happened only twice.

Comment: @MHogge have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @ono not yet sorry. This is not happening a lot so it's kind of difficult to debug it.